# SQL Server Grouping by week year error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query where i'm trying to group an average score by weeks. The issue i'm having is that all the dates are being returned as 2018. How can I get the year of the returned date to be correct

```
DECLARE @s DATETIME= '2017-12-18', @e DATETIME= '2018-01-15';
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(MYTABLE.score AS FLOAT)), 1) AS avgScore,
       DATEADD(week, DATEPART(wk, dateCreated) - 1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 0)) AS dateCreated
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE MYTABLE.dateCreated BETWEEN @s AND @e
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, dateCreated)
ORDER BY dateCreated;
```

Smaple results

```
avgScore | dateCreated
----------------------
5.2      | 2018-12-17
4.6      | 2018-12-24
5.5      | 2018-01-01
6.5      | 2018-01-08
4.2      | 2018-01-15
```

Comment: Don't have a column alias equal to a column name... Chose another column alias!

Comment: You *are* using `GETDATE()` as your base year. Instead of grouping by `DATEPART(wk, dateCreated)` and trying to recreate the original date use a Calendar table with dates, years and week numbers. The query will be a LOT easier and *faster* as the server won't have to calculate week numbers and years. You could even add a WeekStart or WeekEnd to the Calendar table to convert the query to a simple JOIN and `Group BY Calendar.Year,Calendar.WeekNumber`

Comment: If you want to do it this way, you need to group by week **and** year as a value like "week 43" doesn't tell you if it was this year, last year or year 1066. So something like `GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, dateCreated), DATEPART(yyyy, dateCreated)`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

> YEAR(dateCreated)

in the Group By

```
declare @s datetime = '2017-12-18', @e datetime = '2018-01-15';


SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(MYTABLE.score AS FLOAT)), 1) AS avgScore, dateadd(week,DATEPART(wk, dateCreated)-1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), 0)) AS dateCreated
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE MYTABLE.dateCreated between @s and @e 
GROUP BY YEAR(dateCreated), DATEPART(wk, dateCreated) 
ORDER BY dateCreated
```

Being that you are grouping by week, the week is just a number. so you are discarding year.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the first day of the week `DATEADD(DAY, -1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [DATE]), [DATE])` more appropriate and also you can use it with group by.

```
SET DATEFIRST  1;
declare @s datetime = '2017-12-18', @e datetime = '2018-01-15';

SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(MYTABLE.score AS FLOAT)), 1) AS avgScore, 
DATEADD(DAY, -1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dateCreated), dateCreated)  AS dateCreated
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE MYTABLE.dateCreated between @s and @e 
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, -1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dateCreated), dateCreated)  
ORDER BY dateCreated
```